# R: Scoping error when calling function from script

Tags: r, function, environment, scoping

I am building a large codebase in R that uses vectorization through many nested user-defined functions. These auxiliary functions are, by in large, written in their own R script for debugging and maintenance purposes. I would like to source some of these scripts within a specific environment, without the functions being called into the Global Environment.

I am trying to make the main.R file as clean and understandable as possible, so that there are scripts that do the *dirty work* behind the scenes.

In the example below, the global environment becomes populated with `f_foobar` (which is correct), but also `f_foo` and `f_bar` once I call the function `f_foobar`.

Is there an elegant way to house these auxiliary functions (eg `f_foo` and `f_bar`) in a temporary environment?

For example, in file_foo.R:

```
f_foo <- function() {
  return('a')
}
```

In file_bar.R:

```
f_bar <- function() {
  return('b')
}
```

In file_foobar.R:

```
f_foobar <- function() {
  source('file_foo.R')
  source('file_bar.R')
  
  value_foo <- f_foo()
  value_bar <- f_bar()
  
  c(value_foo, value_bar) %>% return
}
```

In main.R:

```
source('file_foobar.R')

main_result <-f_foobar()
```

Comment: "Is there an elegant way..." yes, create a package.

Comment: +1 for the package. But I suggest you read [`?source`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/source.html), particularly: `local: ... 'FALSE' (the default) corresponds to the user's workspace (the global environment) and 'TRUE' to the environment from which 'source' is called.` Use `source("file_foo.R", local=TRUE)`, and your scoping should be resolved. (But really ... a [package](https://r-pkgs.org/).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bottom line: use `source(..., local=TRUE)`. From [`?source`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/source.html):

```
   local: 'TRUE', 'FALSE' or an environment, determining where the
          parsed expressions are evaluated.  'FALSE' (the default)
          corresponds to the user's workspace (the global environment)
          and 'TRUE' to the environment from which 'source' is called.
```

### Before

```r
ls()
# character(0)
source('file_foobar.R')
main_result <- f_foobar()
main_result
# [1] "a" "b"
ls()
# [1] "f_bar"       "f_foo"       "f_foobar"    "main_result"
```

### After

```r
ls()
# character(0)
source('file_foobar.R')
main_result <- f_foobar()
main_result
# [1] "a" "b"
ls()
# [1] "f_foobar"    "main_result"
```

---

(But really, when you talk about *"within a specific environment"*, that really does speak to using an R package. There are many benefits to doing so, even if you never have the intention of pushing to CRAN. I have about two dozen packages I maintain at work, not CRAN, and while I might be able to scope them individually without being a package, the moment you even *consider* using one project from another, it becomes unnecessarily complex. Packages almost always solve that.)